# Using non-Spring Hibernate JPA DAO classes in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Maven project with a Hibernate JPA persistence layer that I would like to incorporate into some Spring applications (one a web application, and one a command line tool), but I am unsure how to configure this.  The persistence module includes model classes, DAO classes, and the `persistence.xml` file.  I have configured Spring's `EntityManagerFactory` to use the existing `persistence.xml`, but instantiating the DAO classes always results in a `NullPointerException`, as they seem to be unable to locate the persistence unit by name.  Is it possible to use Hibernate JPA classes created outside Spring's context in a Spring application?

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="myapp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<bean id="allProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="singleton" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/db.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:config/log4j.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.app" />

<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myapp"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
</bean>
```

**UserDao.java**

```
public class UserDao extends AbstractDao<User> {
public UserDao() {
    super("myapp");
}
// CRUD methods
```

**AbstractDao.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<T extends DataObject> {
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractDao.class);
private final Map<String, Map<String, String>> connectionDictionaries =
    new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();


public AbstractDao(String dataSourceName) {
  try {
    setUpDataSource(dataSourceName);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Unable to load: ", AbstractDataConstants.DB_PROPERTIES_FILE);
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
...
// Other methods
```

Comment: Maybe this is usefull http://olivergierke.de/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/ see the part 8.8.1 of http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#8.8.1